# Flashing Stock ROM for Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, odin

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4 (I9505)
Android: CyanogenMod 10

I am having problems trying to flash stock ROM on Samsung Galaxy S4 (I9505).

I have tried a couple of the stock ROMs from sammobile, but the ones I tried have all failed using Odin and come up with an error message like `write error fail`.

Can anyone tell me if is there something I am missing for flashing these stock ROMs?

My baseband version is I9505XXUEMJ7.

I have tried:

1. GT-I9505 Galaxy S 4 LTE
   PDA: I9505XXUBMF8
   CSC: I9505O2UBMG1
   MODEM: I9505XXUBMF8
2. GT-I9505 Galaxy S 4 LTE
   PDA: I9505XXUEMK8
   CSC: I9505BTUEMK5
   MODEM: I9505XXUEMK8

Comment: Do you know the model number of your Galaxy S4? (Something like `I9500`)

Comment: Yes Galaxy S4 GTi9505

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with links to the pages where you found the Stock ROM's, and specify which ROM's you used specifically? This'll help us figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I found the ROM's at http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/2/ and have updated my question with that info

Comment: There were 2 different versions of the Samsung Galaxy S4 phone released to the market.

Comment: Yes with the two different processors? I believe mine is the snapdragon model

Comment: What version of Odin are you using? 3.07?

Comment: yes 3.07 is the version I am using of Odin